# In-window popups: How to block UI thread?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm currently implementing a **MessageDialog** control. It is there to replace `MessageBox` entirely and is displayed as an "in-window popup" *(correct UX term needed)*.

Currently, its constructor is private and there is a method `Show`, just like in `MessageBox.Show`. However, `MessageBox` blocks the UI thread and returns a result.

---

What my `MessageDialog` control currently does is having a `Action<MessageDialogResult> callback` parameter which gets called when a button is clicked.

**Utilizing `MessageDialog`**

```
// class MessageDialog
public static void MessageDialog.Confirmation(Window owner, string message, Action<MessageDialogResult> callback);

// When used by other controls
MessageDialog.Confirmation(WindowMain.Singleton, true, (result) =>
{
    if (result.Button == MessageDialogButton.Yes)
    {
        //...
    }
});
```

[image: dialog]

However, having a callback instead of a blocking method call like in  `MessageBox.Show` yields absolutely no benefits for me. It makes things rather complicated. What I'm rather trying to achieve is something like...

```
if (MessageDialog.Confirmation(WindowMain.Singleton, true).Button == MessageDialogButton.Yes)
{
    //...
}
```

... which is much cleaner in my opinion.

The current code behind is basically

1. Create instance of `MessageDialog` and populate content with text
2. Add it to the children of `Window.Content.Children`
3. On button click, call `callback(result)` and remove from `Window.Content.Children`

**The question:** What I would like to achieve is having a blocking method call instead of one that triggers a callback.

Comment: So what is your question then?

Comment: See the code block after the screenshot. The question is how to create a thread blocking dialog instead of one that triggers a callback.

Comment: Why do you need to block the UI thread? If you are doing this as an in-window dialog, then you can just have a `Rectangle` that covers the entirety of the screen and displays the dialog on top of it, making the dialog the only interactable control.

Comment: There is no issue with interaction. It is just the utilization of the control that is hard to read and maintain. Instead of passing a callback, I would rather actually block the thread and return the result as a value. This way the code would look just as clean as with `MessageBox.Show`.

Comment: I would also like to point out that if the dialog box exists within the calling window, then it would be a part of that window's UI thread, and blocking the UI thread in that case would block the dialog itself as well.

Comment: Hm, you're right. Then "blocking the UI thread" may be the wrong term. Is there still another way this can be done even if it's not an external window like MessageBox?

Comment: Why not just show the form using [ShowDialog()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx)?  This will make it modal and block any other UI activities.

Comment: Because this is not a Window, but a UserControl. The game using a Window is simple, but with an in-window popup, there is either no way or I haven't found it out yet, or callbacks are the canonical solutions afterall?

Comment: So what is your ultimate goal then? What do you want to prohibit? The user from interacting with objects in the background? A particular process running while the dialog is open? Or do you just want the code to pause until the dialog closes? In the latter case, a callback may be your best choice. Another option I can maybe see is to multithread the code that shows the dialog and block *that* thread, but that solution strikes me as making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Yes, the ultimate goal is making it *less* complicated and therefore pause the code and having a return value instead of `Func<ReturnValueType> callback`. If it is not achievable without worsening code and breaking patterns, then I'll stick to the callback. Otherwise I'm very curious if there is a way to handle such situations.

Comment: You cannot pause the code without blocking the thread, which you do **not** want to do when the dialog exists on the same thread. In this case, your only two options are using a callback or multithreading the entire procedure. Of the two options, I'd greatly advocate the callback option as the much simpler choice.

Comment: Okay. Thanks, though! I'll leave the question here and I consider it answered.

Comment: I would suggest using `await` instead of a callback - that will make your code a lot cleaner. You can implement this yourself by using a `TaskCompletionSource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
//DialogControl.cs
bool _closed = false;
DialogResult _result;

DialogResult ShowModal()
{
    this.Show();
    while(!_closed) Application.DoEvents();  //Infinite loop
    return _result;
}

public void OkButton_OnClick(EventArgs e, object sender)
{
    _result = DialogResult.OK;
    _closed = true;
}

public void CancelButton_OnClick(EventArgs e, object sender)
{
    _result = DialogResult.Cancel;
    _closed = true;
}
```

Comment: This is actually very good! I just tested it and it seems to work. Background logic is still running (side note: Multiple MessageDialogs can be displayed in this case, but this is preferred behavior). Also, I use ` Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(delegate { }));` since `Application.DoEvents` is for Windows Forms. But despite that, this is a great solution! +1

Answer (score 3):

Even though the accepted answer seems to work, I propose a better solution using `TaskCompletionSource`. This is exactly what `await` was made for - it's still basically just a callback (won't block the thread), but your code looks a lot simpler when using it.

```
TaskCompletionSource<DialogResult> taskSource;

Task<DialogResult> ShowAsync()
{
    return taskSource.Task;
}

public void OkButton_OnClick(EventArgs e, object sender)
{
    taskSource.SetResult(DialogResult.OK);
}

public void CancelButton_OnClick(EventArgs e, object sender)
{
    taskSource.SetResult(DialogResult.Cancel);
}
```

You then have to await the call: `await Dialog.ShowAsync()`

Comment: Even though `Task`is superior and more current than `Func` - Having it async is not a problem, since the dialog doesn't cause a delay, it pops up instantly and waits for user input. While it may seem counter intuitive having a while loop and waiting for a boolean value to toggle - In this case it is clearly superior over the code I posted in my question. And since Task doesn't make utilization easier, I will accept John's answer. Thanks for the input, though.

Comment: @Abion47 you're wrong. This is exactly how MessageDialog works in UWP. I was just trying to do the same thing here.

Comment: When waiting for asynchronous tasks, you're also dealing with a callback. You could just as well do `ContinueWith()` - `await` just makes this a lot easier by making those callbacks look like continuous, linear code.

Comment: I would personally use this approach, as async/await is a common pattern that should be familiar to developers to work with.  Further, the not-really-blocking blocking that happens with Application.DoEvents can lead to some unexpected behavior that would not be easily predicted when looking at the API.  At least with `await`, the user of your method is made aware that another event handler may run before the current handler resumes.